# How to add values to "Application Configuration Tool" in RFT from command line

Tags: rft

I am using RFT. I got a requirement, I want to add the values to the `"Application Configuration Tool"` say `"Name","kind","Path" etc.`, through command line in RFT tool.

I have used the following command to open the `"Application configuration Tool" Dialog box` and selected the Project, but i don't know how to give the values to the fields .

```
cmd>java -classpath 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\SDP\FunctionalTester\bin\rational_ft.jar" 
 com.rational.test.ft.rational_ft -appconfig "workbench" .
```

Can any one please tell me how to add the values to the fields to the "Application Configuration tool" from command line in RFT?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, RFT does not currently support setting the Application Configuration fields you require via the command line.  I was supprised to find this out, but I verfied this with IBM.  However, you can add new application configurations programatially by modifying the configurations.rftcfg file.

On a Windows 7 machine, an example of where you can find this file is here:
C:\ProgramData\IBM\RFT\configuration

More information on how to do this can be found here:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/configure-applications-programmatically-rational-functional-tester/index.html

Just an idea and I have not tried this, but possibly, since you run from the command line, your command line can run an RFT script that does nothing more add a new appliation to the configurations.rftcfg file, before you then run other scripts from the command line.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Thanks for your post. Now I am out of that project. ;)